# Site to site network tunneling program

Tags: networking, vpn, tunnel, stunnel

This will sound a bit strange, but I am looking for a(n) (open source?) program that I saw in a Google search some time ago.  I cannot remember, for the life of me, what the site was.

The program does site to site tunneling using various protocols.

It has a client server architecture and allows daisy chaining.  It is written/maintained by an Asian author (told you, strange, but that's what I remember about the product!)

It is (I think) open source, and you can download and build the components yourself.

Now, I cannot find this site/program, but am trying to see if anyone else has seen/used it and can post the link to it.

**UPDATE** (can't post answer in less than 8 hours, so editing the question):
By some bizzare luck, I came across the site I was looking for!

The program is called "DeleGate" and can be found at http://www.delegate.org/delegate/. It is a pretty impressive piece of software written by Yutaka Sato.

Answer (score 2):

Many open source projects have multiple contributors, often from many different countries throughout the world.  Sometimes various people are given credit for doing more (or less) than they actually did, which can add further confusion as well.

For site-to-site tunneling, there are a variety of solutions -- I'm not sure which one you're referring to in particular, but the one that I really like is OpenVPN:

OpenVPN (free and open source)
  http://www.openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/overview.html

This solution supports multiple platforms, and it uses UDP (default) or TCP for making its connections (which has many advantages over IPsec such as avoiding certain complications with firewall configurations).

OpenVPN is highly configurable, secure, reliable, incurs low overhead, and has great documentation.  I have it set up for many sites, most of which are businesses who depend on it daily.  *(I also know a few people who depend on OpenVPN for casual personal use.)*

(*If you need to support it on Apple's MacOS, follow this link to a port of OpenVPN called TunnelBlick:*  http://code.google.com/p/tunnelblick/)

Comment: Thank you for the quick update ... though I am familiar with OpenVPN, and it's now what I saw.  This program was authored by one person, IIRC.

Comment: @HanSooloo "authored by one person" would not go down well in a corporate environment - but this may not be an issue for your needs.

Comment: @Linker3000 my need is very personal and does not involve a business environment.  It's more of a "I saw this program and I know I needed it, but now I cannot find the URL for it" situation :-(

Answer (score 1):

By some bizarre luck, I came across the site I was looking for!

The program is called **[DeleGate](http://www.delegate.org/delegate/)**.  It is a pretty impressive piece of software written by Yutaka Sato.

[image]

Comment: Glad you found it again!

Answer (score 0):

My favorite two tunneling tools are the UN-managed version of [Hamachi](https://secure.logmein.com/products/hamachi/download.aspx) and Bitwise SSHD.